# spring-mvc binding arraylist in form

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

In my controller I added an ArrayList to my model with the attribute name "users".

Now I looked around and this is the method I found (including a question here):

```
<form:form action="../user/edit" method="post" modelAttribute="users">
            <table>
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="counter">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                                <form:input path="users[${counter.index}].age"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><button type="submit" name="updateId" id="Update" value="${user.id}">Update</button></td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </form:form>
```

But when I load the JSP page I get:

> .springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException:
>   Invalid property 'projects[0]' of bean
>   class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean
>   property 'users[0]' is not readable or
>   has an invalid getter method: Does the
>   return type of the getter match the
>   parameter type of the setter?

So apparantely this isn't the way to go, but in that case how do I bind an arraylist so I can edit the values?

Comment: Can you add the code of the controller method where the data is sent?

Answer (score 1):

Try following code :

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
    <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${users.age}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

and make sure that you have **users arraylist** in the request scope.. Or else use add following code:

```
<jsp:useBean id="users" scope="request" type="java.util.Collection" />
```